# Merging two Pandas DataFrames based on the sequential order of two columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, sorting, merge

I know questions related to this one have been asked multiple times, but I can't find anything specific this one. I have gone through pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/merging.html but I still can't find what I need.

I have two very large output files that I need to merge together, based on the timestamp column of each file. I need the timestamp columns to interleave together in sequential order. Here is an example.

```
df1
x1   y1   z1
25   12   0.71
16   13   0.63
41   13   0.84
3    14   0.55
25   17   0.49

df2
x2   y2   z2
73   11   0.31
105  12   0.57
64   12   0.86
92   13   0.42
92   15   0.63
81   18   0.74
```

I need these DataFrames merged based on the sequential order of the y1 and y2 columns.

```
df3
x3   y3   z3
73   11   0.31
25   12   0.71
105  12   0.57
64   12   0.86
41   13   0.84
92   13   0.42
3    14   0.55
92   15   0.63
25   17   0.49
81   18   0.74
```

So far I have tried using Pandas concat with sort_values.

```
df3 = pd.concat([df1,df2]).sort_values(by=['y1','y2'], ascending=True)
```

Unfortunately I keep getting errors this way. I know there's a way to do this, but I haven't been able to find it. Can anyone offer advice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The column names differ - you could rename the columns in one of the dataframes so they align.

```
pd.concat([
   df1,
   df2.rename(columns=dict(zip(df2.columns, df1.columns)))
]).sort_values("y1")
```

```
    x1  y1    z1
0   73  11  0.31
0   25  12  0.71
1  105  12  0.57
2   64  12  0.86
1   16  13  0.63
2   41  13  0.84
3   92  13  0.42
3    3  14  0.55
4   92  15  0.63
4   25  17  0.49
5   81  18  0.74
```

You can use `ignore_index=True` in the `.concat` if desired.

Comment: Lol! Yeah, I just found that. The .concat function kept offsetting the data frames. I only realized that a few minutes ago. Now the .sort_values function sorts the data frame the way I need it. I feel so stupid right now, since it's such an easy fix.

Answer (score 1):

To make it easier to combine (concatenate) two dataframes vertically, first rename both the dataframes;

```
df1.columns = ['x', 'y', 'z']
df2.columns = ['x', 'y', 'z']
```

Once the column are renamed, we can `sort_values` at column `y`. Use `ignore_index = True` to generate new row index.

```
pd.concat([df_1, df_2], ignore_index=True).sort_values('y')
```

Output:

```
    x   y   z
5   73  11  0.31
0   25  12  0.71
6   105 12  0.57
7   64  12  0.86
1   16  13  0.63
2   41  13  0.84
8   92  13  0.42
3   3   14  0.55
9   92  15  0.63
4   25  17  0.49
10  81  18  0.74
```